# nsmutablearray objectatindex is null or not

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have problem.

```
-(NSString*) get_readMessage:(int)index
{
    if ([msg objectAtIndex:index] == NSNotFound) //not Working
        return @"-1";
    return [msg objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

lets assume [msg count] is 10 and in the program, we call this function with

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self get_readMessage:11]);
```

and now we are out of size of array. crashing application.
is there way to check such as "msg[11]==mull;" in objective C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the count.

```
- (NSString*)get_readMessage:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (index >= msg.count) {
        return @"-1";
    } else {
        return msg[index];
    }
}
```

Also, change the `index` to `NSUInteger`.

And standard naming conventions suggest your method should be named more like `readMessage:`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But count doesn't help me. I need to know that specific object at that index is exists or not...

Comment: I don't think you understand how an array works. The index is either in range or it isn't. If it is in range, you get the object from that index, whatever the object is. That is what my answer gives you. It makes no sense to say "check if a specific object at that index exists".